# .Net Regex match grouping and repetition question

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, regex, asp.net-2.0

I have the following VB.Net 2.0 in an ASP.Net app:

```
output = Regex.Replace(output, "<p>(?:(?:\<\!\-\-.*?\-\-\>)|&(?:nbsp|\#0*160|x0*A0);|<br\s*/?>|[\s\u00A0]+)*</p>", String.Empty, RegexOptions.Compiled Or RegexOptions.CultureInvariant Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

Example stuff it matches well:

- `<p></p>`
- `<p>  </p>`
- `<p><br/><br/></p>`
- `<p><!-- comment --><!-- comment --></p>`
- `<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>`
- `<p><br/>&nbsp;</p>`
- `<p><!-- comment --><br/><!-- comment --></p>`
- `<p>&nbsp;<br/></p>`

Examples of stuff I'd like to match but it doesn't:

- `<p > <!--[if !supportLineBreakNewLine]--><br /> <!--[endif]--></p>`

How do I make the groups and repetitions work how I want them to?

**Edit:** oops, forgot the comment group.
**Edit #2:** oops, forgot a fail.
**Edit #3:** fixed examples.
**Edit #4:** updated regex based on answers

**Conclusion:**

Here are my benchmarked results for all three answers. Since all three now match everything I ran each one through 10,000 iterations on a block of text:

```
Mine:
<p\s*>(?:(?:<!--.*?-->)|&(?:nbsp|\#0*160|x0*A0);|<br\s*/?>|[\s\u00A0]+)*</p>
6.312

Gumbo:
<p\s*>(?:[\s\u00A0]+|&(?:nbsp|\#0*160|x0*A0);|<br\s*/?>|<!--(?:[^-]+|-(?!-))*-->)*</p>
6.05

steamer25:
<p\s*>(?:(?:\&nbsp\;)|(?:\&\#0*160\;)|(?:<br\s*/?>)|\s|\u00A0|<!\-\-[^(?:\-\-)]*\-\->)*</p>
6.121
```

Gumbo's was the fastest, so I'll mark his as the correct answer.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to strip all P tags from html content that only contain: html comments, non-breaking spaces, BR elements, or whitespace characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
<p\s*>(?:[\s\u00A0]+|&(?:nbsp|\#0*160|x0*A0);|<br\s*/?>|<!--(?:[^-]+|-(?!-))*-->)*</p>
```

Comment: Seems to be missing a ')' somewhere

Comment: ah, I had to escape the '#' still doesn't seem to match that last item

Answer (score 1):

```
<p\s*>(?:(?:\&nbsp\;)|(?:\&\#0*160\;)|(?:<br\s*/?>)|\s|\u00A0|<!\-\-[^(?:\-\-)]*\-\->)*</p>
```

You don't need to escape angle brackets <> and I've added comments.

Comment: thanks for the tip on the angle brackets still doesn't match that last item correctly though

Answer (score 1):

UGH! I see my problem, it was in the P tag itself, not the grouping.

```
<p\s*>(?:(?:<!--.*?-->)|&(?:nbsp|\#0*160|x0*A0);|<br\s*/?>|[\s\u00A0]+)*</p>
```

Notice the \s* in the tag. Points for all!